# c# dotnet CLI "error: There are no versions available for the package 'Newtonsoft.Json'."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, cmd, package, dotnet-cli

I am new to c# , I am trying to add package to my project I tried  before to add "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications" by dotnet cli `dotnet add package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` , and then tried to mimic Microsoft example [Microsoft.Docs](http://%5Bwindows.Docs%5D%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package)  but it always  shows this error , any help please?

info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' into project 'C:\Users\moham\cs\cs.csproj'.
error: There are no versions available for the package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.

### EDIT :

when I tried `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json --version 13.0.1` I got this error : [CMD error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/596M9.png)

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue, I fix it running this command

```
dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

See this issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4156 for more details.

Hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of C#! While `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` doesn't appear to be dependent on `Newtonsoft.Json`, there may be another dependency in your project file. May I have you try adding `Newtonsoft.Json` FIRST, and then attempt to add the `Mictrosoft.Toolkiy.Uwp.Notifications` package afterwards?

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json --version 13.0.1
dotnet add package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications --version 7.0.1
```

Comment: I know , I am just trying to add any package to learn how to use dotnet cli , I got this error : NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Newtonsoft.Json (>= 13.0.1)' for 'net5.0'.
error: Package 'Newtonsoft.Json' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Users\moham\cs\cs.csproj'.

Comment: May I see a screenshot of what your .csproj file contains? That error sounds like something is being referenced that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I added the screenshot ,can you please take a look on it ,